# PyQT5 slot parameters not updating after first call

Tags: pyqt5, signals-slots

I have a signal that connects to a slot that I use to change an x-range span on a matplotlib plot. I am trying to update the span when a user changes the starting x value in a table that shows all the spans. However, after the first edit of the span, the proceeding edits all act as though they are editing the same span, rather than the newly selected span. When running the code:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def xStartChanged(xStart, rowVal):
        if self.inCounter == 0:
            print( "row in start changed: ", rowVal)
            print("xStart in start changed: ", xStart)
            print(type(xStart))
            tagName = self.highlights[xStart].tag
            xEnd = self.highlights[xStart].xEnd
            xStartNew = int(self.taggingTable.item(rowVal, 1).text())
            self.highlights[xStart].highlightObj.remove() #remove old from the plot
            del self.highlights[xStart]                   #remove old from directory
            highlightObj = self.Axes.axvspan(xStartNew, xEnd, color = 'blue', alpha = 0.5) #add new to plot
            
            self.highlights[xStartNew] = highlight(tagName, xStartNew, xEnd, highlightObj) #add new to directory
            self.taggingTable.clearSelection() #deselect value from table
            self.draw_idle()#update plot
        self.inCounter = self.inCounter + 1

     def onCellSelect():
            index = self.taggingTable.selectedIndexes()
            if len(index) != 0:
                rowVal = index[0].row()
                #get the starting adn ending indices so they can be edited. 
                ##deal with empty cell click
                if not (self.taggingTable.item(rowVal, 1) is None):
                    xStart = int(self.taggingTable.item(rowVal, 1).text())
                    print("row in cell select: ", rowVal)
                    print("xStart in cell select: ", xStart)
                    xEnd = int(self.taggingTable.item(rowVal, 2).text())
                    self.inCounter = 0
                    #self.taggingTable.itemChanged.connect(lambda state, item = None, xStartVal = xStart, rowValFxn = rowVal: xStartChanged(xStartVal, rowValFxn))
                    print(type(xStart))
                    self.taggingTable.itemChanged.connect(lambda item = None, xStart = xStart: xStartChanged(xStart, rowVal))
                    self.draw_idle()
                    #self.taggingTable.itemChanged.connect(xEndChanged)
                
    #self.taggingTable.cellDoubleClicked.connect(onCellSelect)
    self.taggingTable.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(onCellSelect)
    self.draw_idle()
```

I get the following output: (NOTE: I have hidden the "path" because it is work related, sorry.

```
row in cell select:  0
xStart in cell select:  3517
<class 'int'>
row in start changed:  0
xStart in start changed:  3517
<class 'int'>
row in cell select:  1
xStart in cell select:  2801
<class 'int'>
row in start changed:  0
xStart in start changed:  3517
<class 'int'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path", line 314, in <lambda>
    self.taggingTable.itemChanged.connect(lambda item = None, xStart = xStart: xStartChanged(xStart, rowVal))
  File "path", line 277, in xStartChanged
    tagName = self.highlights[xStart].tag
KeyError: 3517
zsh: abort      path
```

I understand that for some reason, the connection sends the row value and xStart value of 0 and 3517 and after the cell is changed and edited, the first slot function (onCellSelect) is reading the new cell and xStart values, but the nested signal-slot connection (xStartChanged) is still holding onto the older cell and xStart values. I'm assuming that I am calling or initializing it wrong in some way. Is there something i'm not realizing?

**EDIT:** minimal reproducible example.

```py
    import sys
   
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    from PyQt5 import QtCore
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *
    
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    import matplotlib.widgets as mwidgets
    
    class Window(QMainWindow):
    
        def __init__(self, parent = None):
            super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
            self.resize(1600, 800)
            self.MyUI()
            
        def MyUI(self):
    
            canvas = Canvas(self, width=14, height=12, dpi=100)
            canvas.move(0,0)
    
    class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
        def __init__(self, parent, width = 14, height = 12, dpi = 100):
            Plot = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
            self.Axes = Plot.add_subplot(111)
            self.Axes.set_position([0.05, 0.58, 0.66, 0.55])
            self.rowCount = 0
            super().__init__(Plot)
            self.setParent(parent)
    
            
            ##add all relevant lines to plot 
            self.Axes.plot([0,1,2,3,4], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
            self.Axes.set_xlabel('Frame', fontsize = 10) 
            self.Axes.grid()
            self.Axes.set_aspect(1)
            Plot.canvas.draw()
    
    
            #use this object in the dictionary to hold onto all the spans. 
            class highlight:
                def __init__(self, tag, xStart, xEnd, highlightObj):
                    self.tag = tag
                    self.xStart = xStart
                    self.xEnd = xEnd
                    self.highlightObj = highlightObj
    
            self.highlights = {} #empty dictionary to store all the tags.
    
            ##define a table to hold the values postselection
            self.taggingTable = QTableWidget(self)
            self.taggingTable.setColumnCount(3)
            self.taggingTable.setRowCount(100)
            self.taggingTable.setGeometry(QRect(1005,85, 330, 310))
            self.taggingTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Behavior','Start Frame', 'End Frame'])
    
            ##highlighting adds a highlight item to the directory. 
            def onHighlight(xStart, xEnd):
                tagName = "No Tag"
                self.taggingTable.setItem(self.rowCount, 0, QTableWidgetItem(tagName))
                self.taggingTable.setItem(self.rowCount, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(int(xStart))))
                self.taggingTable.setItem(self.rowCount, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(int(xEnd))))
                self.rowCount = self.rowCount + 1
                highlightObj = self.Axes.axvspan(xStart, xEnd, color = 'blue', alpha = 0.5)
                self.highlights[int(xStart)] = highlight(tagName, xStart, xEnd, highlightObj)
                self.draw_idle()
                    
            self.span = mwidgets.SpanSelector(self.Axes, onHighlight, "horizontal", 
                                            interactive = True, useblit=True, props=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor="blue"),)
            self.draw_idle()
    
            ##TODO: editing spans in table is reflected in plot --- use axvspan to track spans? and spanselector to draw them?
            ##define workflow for when a cell is selected
            def xStartChanged(xStart, rowVal):
                if self.inCounter == 0:
                    print( "row in start changed: ", rowVal)
                    print("xStart in start changed: ", xStart)
                    xEnd = self.highlights[xStart].xEnd
                    xStartNew = int(self.taggingTable.item(rowVal, 1).text())
                    self.highlights[xStart].highlightObj.remove() #remove old from the plot
                    del self.highlights[xStart]                   #remove old from directory
                    highlightObj = self.Axes.axvspan(xStartNew, xEnd, color = 'blue', alpha = 0.5) #add new to plot
                    self.highlights[xStartNew] = highlight("No tagName", xStartNew, xEnd, highlightObj) #add new to directory
                    self.taggingTable.clearSelection() #deselect value from table
                    self.draw_idle()#update plot
                self.inCounter = self.inCounter + 1
    
            def onCellSelect():
                index = self.taggingTable.selectedIndexes()
                if len(index) != 0:
                    rowVal = index[0].row()
                    if not (self.taggingTable.item(rowVal, 1) is None):
                        xStart = int(self.taggingTable.item(rowVal, 1).text())
                        print("row in cell select: ", rowVal)
                        print("xStart in cell select: ", xStart)
                        self.inCounter = 0
                        self.taggingTable.itemChanged.connect(lambda: xStartChanged(xStart, rowVal))              
           
            self.taggingTable.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(onCellSelect)
            self.draw_idle()
    
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

I receive the following error:

```py
    row in cell select:  0
    xStart in cell select:  2
    row in start changed:  0
    xStart in start changed:  2
    row in cell select:  1
    xStart in cell select:  1
    row in start changed:  0
    xStart in start changed:  2
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "path", line 103, in <lambda>
        self.taggingTable.itemChanged.connect(lambda: xStartChanged(xStart, rowVal))              
      File "path", line 84, in xStartChanged
        xEnd = self.highlights[xStart].xEnd
    KeyError: 2
    zsh: abort      "path"
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], as your code is insufficient (and confusing) to really understand what you're doing. For instance, are those local functions? If so, why? Besides, those pyqtSlots decorators are useless: slots should be class attributes, and the arguments are wrong.

Comment: I will be honest, I am not sure how to make one for this, since I am not sure what is going on (i am a newbie). Is it possible that I direct message you and send my entire code?

Comment: Sorry, but no. The purpose of StackOverflow is for general knowledge, it's not a help desk nor a debugging service. Your question (and its answers) *must* be useful to anybody, not just you. Please read very carefully what the above link explains. Try to take away portions of your code that are not relevant for the issue while still ensuring that the issue still reproduces. That's how debugging works, you have to *get to the point*. It might be very difficult at start (especially if you're a beginner), but there's really no other way to achieve that.

Comment: ok. I have added the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Your code has some important issues that make it difficult to understand (and also debug or maintain), like using unnecessary local functions (and class!) and connecting to signals multiple times. Is your intent to update the table whenever a new range is selected and also update the existing ranges by editing values in that table?

Comment: yes. I want it to mimic the signal tagging tool in Matlab (i.e. be able to select ranges on the plot and then be able to retroactively edit the table values and have it reflect on the plot). Could you elaborate on the issue with the local functions and what steps can be taken to avoid connecting to a signal multiple times. What  results from connecting to a signal too many times? which class is unnecessary?

Comment: 1. most of the times, you should create instance methods (functions that are part of the class and that are called from the instance), local functions are only for limited cases; 2. when a signal is emitted, it always calls *any* function that has been connected to it, even with the *same* function: you connect the same function twice? when the signal is emitted, that function will be called twice; 3. the class is not unnecessary, but it's unnecessary (and conceptually wrong for situations like these) to make it *local* to the `__init__` just create a "top level" class.

Comment: Thank you, im a little confused 1. which functions are local functions? does this refer to the methods like onHighlight or xStartChanged in the canvas class? would making them instance methods mean moving them within some other class? 2. Im a little confused on what this refers to. which function was connected to twice? I thought there was one connection for itemChanged and one for selection changed, going to different functions. 3. for this do you mean that all the lines after self.SetParent should be moved out of __init__ and somewhere else? would this somewhere else be in the canvas class?

Comment: 1. those are functions, not methods; in "python terminology", methods are functions part of a class of any of its instances; you don't have to create another class, you have to create *methods* for it; 2. whenever `onCellSelect` is called and the item is valid, a *new* connection is made, meaning that `itemChanged` will be called more than once (as many times at it's connected), whenever ***any*** item has changed; 3. no, I mean that `class highlight` should be a *top level class*, eventually using proper arguments in its constructor and `__init__` (and setting those as instance attributes).

Comment: 1. You mean that because I placed them within the `__init__` , they are local functions, rather than instance methods?  Should I instead move them out of `__init__` but keep them within `canvas` at the same level as `__init__`? So when the `canvas` is instantiated, the methods such as `onHighlight` are called from there? 2. I get that new connection to `onCellSelect` each time new subsets of cells are selected. after the first call, does the connection remain connected, so subsequent changes in selection and changes in item will call old `onCellSelect` and `itemChanged`?

Comment: 3. for this, do you mean moving `class Highlight` out of `canvas` and placing it on the same "level" as  `canvas`, and modeling it after `canvas'?

Comment: 1. Yes; I strongly urge you to do some research on how classes, instances and their methods work; 2. as said, each time you make a new connection to a function, that function will be called along with the previously connected ones (unless the objects those functions refer to are destroyed): you connect it twice, it will be called twice, etc.; 3. yes, after or before is normally irrelevant and their position in the code just a matter of choice (as long as the code is well written), since they'd be called *within* the `__init__` of the other class, which normally happens afterwards anyway.

Comment: 1. Yes, I will do so. Thank you. 2. For this case, I attempted to disconnect the connections after the call. However, this lost the nested connection within `onCellConnected`. What should I look out for or think about in order to maintain the connection only for the duration of the user editing the cell? 3. if I moved the functions out of `__Init__` would connecting to them be the same as I have been doing/

Comment: 2. You can't disconnect from lambdas, unless you keep a reference to them (or disconnect from *any* function); your main issue is based on the wrong concept: that connection should probably be *unique* and eventually evaluate what to do based on the argument of the signal (the changed item). I'll see in the next days if I'll get the chance to better inspect your code and provide an answer that will explain all the above concepts, unless anybody else will do it in the meantime; please be patient (remember that the purpose of StackOverflow is to provide good answers, not *immediate* solutions).

Comment: Thanks, this has been very helpful. Is there any resource that I can look at for information on making unique connections. I have seen some information on signals and slots, but it has been ultimately unclear to me. is there anywhere I can read about them to get a clearer understanding?

Comment: The only way to connect a signal to *only one* slot/function is to force a general disconnection (`obj.signal.disconnect()`) *before* connecting to the new function, which would potentially raise an exception if no previous connection existed, and should also be always used with *extreme* care: Qt sometimes creates internal connections to public signals, and doing the above can have unexpected results. Qt supports "unique connections" in terms of "connecting to the same function just *once*", which is clearly impossible for lambdas (unless you're using a reference to the *same* lambda).

Comment: Instead of connecting to a lambda with a unique connection, I have tried to use the unique connection with functools.partial. The code I have is `self.taggingTable.itemChanged.connect(partial(self.xStartChanged, xStart, rowVal), type=Qt.UniqueConnection)` and `self.taggingTable.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.onCellSelect,  type=Qt.UniqueConnection)` However I run into the same issue.

Comment: Using partial will change absolutely ***nothing***: create two lambdas or partials with the same arguments, you'll ***always*** get two distinct and unique objects, *not* the same. It's like creating two instances from a class: they might be conceptually identical, but they are *not* the same.

Comment: This confuses me. What can I do to ensure that the connection is made once, and not reproduced on each action?

Comment: @musicamante is there something else I can use to connect the signal only once?