# New signal connects to old slot instead of separate slot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, signals-slots, qtablewidget

I am trying to tag x-spans of a data trace and populate a table with tagNames, starting x value, and the ending x value. I am using a dictionary of 'highlight' objects to keep track of the x-spans in case they need to be edited (increased or decreased) later. The dictionary maps the x Start value to the highlight object, as the x start values are expected to be unique (there is no overlap of x-spans for the tagging).

In order to do this, I am emitting a signal when the user beings to edit a cell on the table. The function that the first signal connects to emits another signal (ideally for whether the xStart is changed vs. the xEnd, but I have only implemented the xStart thus far), which actually changes the appearance of the span to match the edit.

I asked a similar question a few weeks ago but wasn't able to get an answer. The old question is here: [PyQT5 slot parameters not updating after first call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72876669/pyqt5-slot-parameters-not-updating-after-first-call). In response to the tips given there, I wrote the following example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.widgets as mwidgets
from functools import partial

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(1600, 800)
        self.MyUI()
        
    def MyUI(self):

        canvas = Canvas(self, width=14, height=12, dpi=100)
        canvas.move(0,0)

 #use this object in the dictionary to hold onto all the spans. 
class highlight:
    def __init__(self, tag, xStart, xEnd, highlightObj):
        self.tag = tag
        self.xStart = xStart
        self.xEnd = xEnd
        self.highlightObj = highlightObj

class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, width = 14, height = 12, dpi = 100):
        Plot = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.Axes = Plot.add_subplot(111)
        self.Axes.set_position([0.05, 0.58, 0.66, 0.55])
        self.rowCount = 0
        super().__init__(Plot)
        self.setParent(parent)

        
        ##add all relevant lines to plot 
        self.Axes.plot([0,1,2,3,4], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
        self.Axes.set_xlabel('Frame', fontsize = 10) 
        self.Axes.grid()
        self.Axes.set_aspect(1)
        Plot.canvas.draw()

        
        self.highlights = {} #empty dictionary to store all the tags.

        ##define a table to hold the values postselection
        self.taggingTable = QTableWidget(self)
        self.taggingTable.setColumnCount(3)
        self.taggingTable.setRowCount(100)
        self.taggingTable.setGeometry(QRect(1005,85, 330, 310))
        self.taggingTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Behavior','Start Frame', 'End Frame'])


        Canvas.span = mwidgets.SpanSelector(self.Axes, self.onHighlight, "horizontal", 
                                        interactive = True, useblit=True, props=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor="blue"),)
        self.draw_idle()

        self.taggingTable.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.onCellSelect)
        self.draw_idle()

        ##highlighting adds a highlight item to the directory. 
    def onHighlight(self, xStart, xEnd):
        tagName = "No Tag"
        self.taggingTable.setItem(self.rowCount, 0, QTableWidgetItem(tagName))
        self.taggingTable.setItem(self.rowCount, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(int(xStart))))
        self.taggingTable.setItem(self.rowCount, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(int(xEnd))))
        self.rowCount = self.rowCount + 1
        highlightObj = self.Axes.axvspan(xStart, xEnd, color = 'blue', alpha = 0.5)
        self.highlights[int(xStart)] = highlight(tagName, xStart, xEnd, highlightObj)
        self.draw_idle()
                
    def xStartChanged(self, xStart, rowVal):
        if self.inCounter == 0:
            print("xStart in slot: ", xStart)
            xEnd = self.highlights[xStart].xEnd
            xStartNew = int(self.taggingTable.item(rowVal, 1).text())
            self.highlights[xStart].highlightObj.remove() #remove old from the plot
            del self.highlights[xStart]                   #remove old from directory
            highlightObj = self.Axes.axvspan(xStartNew, xEnd, color = 'blue', alpha = 0.5) #add new to plot
            self.highlights[xStartNew] = highlight("No tagName", xStartNew, xEnd, highlightObj) #add new to directory
            self.taggingTable.clearSelection() #deselect value from table
            self.draw_idle()
        self.inCounter = self.inCounter + 1

    def onCellSelect(self):
        index = self.taggingTable.selectedIndexes()
        if len(index) != 0:
            rowVal = index[0].row()
            if not (self.taggingTable.item(rowVal, 1) is None):
                xStart = int(self.taggingTable.item(rowVal, 1).text())
                print("--------------")
                print("xStart in signal: ", xStart)
                self.inCounter = 0
                self.taggingTable.itemChanged.connect(lambda: self.xStartChanged(xStart, rowVal))        
    
    


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

A test I run is when I highlight two traces:

[image: two traces and their table values]

and then I successfully change a first trace:

[image: editing first trace]

However, when I attempt to edit the second trace, the program crashes:

[image: editing second trace before hitting enter]

To debug, I tried to check what the signals were emitting and receiving. it produces the following output:

```
--------------
xStart in signal:  0
xStart in slot:  0 ##First slot call gets correct signal 
--------------
xStart in signal:  3
xStart in slot:  0 ## Second slot gets the first signal instead of the second
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//Volumes/path/file.py", line 105, in <lambda>
    self.taggingTable.itemChanged.connect(lambda: self.xStartChanged(xStart, rowVal))        
  File "//Volumes/path/file.py", line 86, in xStartChanged
    xEnd = self.highlights[xStart].xEnd
KeyError: 0
zsh: abort      python Volumes/path file.py
```

I tried to use information online on unique connections but I am not sure how to implement them. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that what you need is table-widget signal that emits an item *and* its old text value whenever a change is made to a specific column. Unfortunately, the [itemChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemChanged) signal isn't really suitable, because it doesn't indicate *what* changed, and it doesn't supply the previous value. So, to work around this limitation, one solution would be to subclass QTableWidget  / QTableWidgetItem and emit a custom signal with the required parameters. This will completely side-step the issue with multiple signal-slot connections.

The implementation of the subclasses is quite simple:

```
class TableWidgetItem(QTableWidgetItem):
    def setData(self, role, value):
        oldval = self.text()
        super().setData(role, value)
        if role == Qt.EditRole and self.text() != oldval:
            table = self.tableWidget()
            if table is not None:
                table.itemTextChanged.emit(self, oldval)

class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    itemTextChanged = pyqtSignal(TableWidgetItem, str)
```

Below is basic a demo based on your example that shows how to use them. (Note that I have made no attempt to handle xEnd as well, as that would go beyond the scope of the immediate issue).

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.widgets as mwidgets

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(1600, 800)
        self.MyUI()

    def MyUI(self):
        canvas = Canvas(self, width=14, height=12, dpi=100)
        canvas.move(0,0)

# CUSTOM SUBCLASSES

class TableWidgetItem(QTableWidgetItem):
    def setData(self, role, value):
        oldval = self.text()
        super().setData(role, value)
        if role == Qt.EditRole and self.text() != oldval:
            table = self.tableWidget()
            if table is not None:
                table.itemTextChanged.emit(self, oldval)

class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    itemTextChanged = pyqtSignal(TableWidgetItem, str)


 #use this object in the dictionary to hold onto all the spans.
class highlight:
    def __init__(self, tag, xStart, xEnd, highlightObj):
        self.tag = tag
        self.xStart = xStart
        self.xEnd = xEnd
        self.highlightObj = highlightObj

class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, width = 14, height = 12, dpi = 100):
        Plot = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.Axes = Plot.add_subplot(111)
        self.Axes.set_position([0.05, 0.58, 0.66, 0.55])
        self.rowCount = 0
        super().__init__(Plot)
        self.setParent(parent)

        ##add all relevant lines to plot
        self.Axes.plot([0,1,2,3,4], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
        self.Axes.set_xlabel('Frame', fontsize = 10)
        self.Axes.grid()
        self.Axes.set_aspect(1)
        Plot.canvas.draw()

        self.highlights = {} #empty dictionary to store all the tags.

        ##define a table to hold the values postselection
        # USE CUSTOM TABLE SUBCLASS
        self.taggingTable = TableWidget(self)
        self.taggingTable.setColumnCount(3)
        self.taggingTable.setRowCount(100)
        self.taggingTable.setGeometry(QRect(1005,85, 330, 310))
        self.taggingTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Behavior','Start Frame', 'End Frame'])
        # CONNECT TO CUSTOM SIGNAL
        self.taggingTable.itemTextChanged.connect(self.xStartChanged)

        Canvas.span = mwidgets.SpanSelector(self.Axes, self.onHighlight, "horizontal",
                                        interactive = True, useblit=True, props=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor="blue"),)
        self.draw_idle()

        ##highlighting adds a highlight item to the directory.
    def onHighlight(self, xStart, xEnd):
        tagName = "No Tag"
        self.taggingTable.setItem(self.rowCount, 0, QTableWidgetItem(tagName))
        # USE CUSTOM ITEM SUBCLASS
        self.taggingTable.setItem(self.rowCount, 1, TableWidgetItem(str(int(xStart))))
        self.taggingTable.setItem(self.rowCount, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(int(xEnd))))
        self.rowCount = self.rowCount + 1
        highlightObj = self.Axes.axvspan(xStart, xEnd, color = 'blue', alpha = 0.5)
        self.highlights[int(xStart)] = highlight(tagName, xStart, xEnd, highlightObj)
        self.draw_idle()

    def xStartChanged(self, item, oldVal):
        try:
            # VALIDATE NEW VALUES
            xStart = int(oldVal)
            xStartNew = int(item.text())
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            print("xStart in slot: ", xStart)
            xEnd = self.highlights[xStart].xEnd
            self.highlights[xStart].highlightObj.remove() #remove old from the plot
            del self.highlights[xStart]                   #remove old from directory
            highlightObj = self.Axes.axvspan(xStartNew, xEnd, color = 'blue', alpha = 0.5) #add new to plot
            self.highlights[xStartNew] = highlight("No tagName", xStartNew, xEnd, highlightObj) #add new to directory
            self.taggingTable.clearSelection() #deselect value from table
            self.draw_idle()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec()
```